# Accidental flag, what should I do?

Tags: support, flags

I accidentally flagged a question as offensive when I meant to flag it as off topic (on mobile, clumsy fingers, sorry). It's still a flag, but it's for the wrong reason.

If relevant, it's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714779/word-messy-appearance-text) question.

What should I do?

Comment: I don't see this as a duplicate anymore.  The linked question is for the ability to **cancel** a flag.  This question is asking about steps to take if a question deserves a close vote but you accidentally clicked the wrong reason, e.i. **change** a flag.  What should you do in that circumstance?  Should you retract the vote since it will be declined?  Should you leave the vote since it still deserves to be closed?

Comment: @zero298, That is a duplicate, because the answer to the question of flagging in error is, *cancel the flag*.  That is what was implemented...

Answer (score 4):

You cannot really do anything; flags cannot be cancelled. You'll have to wait for a moderator to handle the flag - who will probably decline it.

Comment: I guess I'll just support the [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags) then.